# Building an Employee Date Matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, matrix

I have a list of employees, along with list of cities they've worked in. I need to build a matrix (in SQL Server) of start/end dates by city to determine where they were at any given period in time.

The "end date" would be exactly the date before they appeared at a new location.

I've included an example of the source table, and what the output table should appear, along with the code that will build a temp table.

Any recommendations on how I can design this query, and what functions to use?

SOURCE:

```
EMP     DATE        LOCATION
-----------------------------------
Pinal   2020-01-01  Bangalore
Pinal   2020-01-02  Bangalore
Pinal   2020-01-04  Uttar Pradesh
Pinal   2020-01-06  Uttar Pradesh
Pinal   2020-01-20  Mumbai
Pinal   2020-01-22  Bangalore
```

Desired query output:

```
EMP     DATE_FROM   DATE_TO     LOCATION
----------------------------------------------
Pinal   2020-01-01  2020-01-03  Bangalore
Pinal   2020-01-04  2020-01-19  Uttar Pradesh
Pinal   2020-01-20  2020-01-21  Mumbai
Pinal   2020-01-22  2099-01-01  Bangalore


CREATE TABLE #EMP 
(
    EMP VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL  ,
    DATE_WORKED DATE NOT NULL ,
    CITY VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #EMP (EMP, DATE_WORKED, CITY) 
VALUES 
('Pinal','2020-01-01','Bangalore'),
('Pinal','2020-01-02','Bangalore'),
('Pinal','2020-01-04','Uttar Pradesh'),
('Pinal','2020-01-06','Uttar Pradesh'),
('Pinal','2020-01-20','Mumbai'),
('Pinal','2020-01-22','Bangalore')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic Gaps-and-Islands.

Here we use a `CROSS APPLY B` to get the Date Range, and then `CROSS APPLY C` as an ad-hoc tally table

**Example**

```
 Select Emp
      ,FromDate = min(D)
      ,ToDate   = max(D)
      ,City
 From (
Select *
      ,Grp = datediff(day,'1900-01-01',d) - row_number() over (partition by Emp,City Order By D)
 From  #Emp A
 Cross Apply (
               Select NextDate = IsNull(min(DateAdd(DAY,-1,Date_Worked)),'2025-01-01')
                From  #Emp 
                Where Emp=A.Emp and Date_Worked>A.Date_Worked
             ) B
 Cross Apply (
               Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,Date_Worked,NextDate)+1) 
                      D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),Date_Worked) 
                From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
             ) C
 --Where EMP ='Victor'
) A
Group By Emp,City,Grp
Order by Emp,FromDate
```

**Returns**

```
Emp     FromDate    ToDate      City
Pinal   2020-01-01  2020-01-03  Bangalore
Pinal   2020-01-04  2020-01-19  Uttar Pradesh
Pinal   2020-01-20  2020-01-21  Mumbai
Pinal   2020-01-22  2025-01-01  Banga
Victor  2020-01-01  2020-01-18  NYC
Victor  2020-01-19  2020-01-24  San Fran
Victor  2020-01-25  2025-01-01  NYC
```

Comment: Thx John! However when you add employees, it generates multiple records for consecutive cities worked:

CREATE TABLE #EMP  ( EMP VARCHAR(30), DATE_WORKED DATE,
CITY VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO #EMP (EMP, DATE_WORKED, CITY) VALUES 
('Pinal','2020-01-01','Bangalore'),
('Pinal','2020-01-02','Bangalore'),
('Pinal','2020-01-04','Uttar Pradesh'),
('Pinal','2020-01-06','Uttar Pradesh'),
('Pinal','2020-01-20','Mumbai'),
('Pinal','2020-01-22','Banga'),
('Pinal','2020-02-22','Banga'),
('Victor','2020-01-01','NYC'),
('Victor','2020-01-12','NYC'),
('Victor','2020-01-19','San Fran')

Comment: I'll take a peek when I get back home.   1 hour ish.

Comment: @DepthofField Corrected (I think).  Was missing a partition in the GRP calc

Comment: Hey John! Thanks again for having another look! But now something else is off. If you Add this value to the table, then you'll see what I mean:

('Victor','2020-01-25','NYC')

Comment: @DepthofField Sometimes when working on a small sample, you can get a false positive.   I think I got it this time  :)

Comment: @DepthofField Notice the "split" in Victor  Hope we got it this time  :)

Comment: @DepthofField Thanks for the grin.  I'm sure my wife would dispute that assertion. :)

Comment: A previous colleague achieved this as several loop/merge operations. It involved 4 stored procedures, and code that the most senior DBAs couldn't grasp. This procedure truncated the code down to 5% of what it used to be.

Comment: @DepthofField Always nice to know there was a value-add.   FYI - Loops should be avoided when possible.  SQL Server was designed for set-based solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the windows functions like this:

```
with cte as
(

select distinct EMP, 
case when city = lag(CITY)over(partition by EMP order by DATE_WORKED) 
then lag(DATE_WORKED)over(partition by EMP order by DATE_WORKED) else 
 DATE_WORKED end as DATE_FROM, CITY 
 from 
#EMP a --order by DATE_WORKED
)
select EMP, CITY as LOCATION, DATE_FROM, 
case when dateadd(d,-1,lead(DATE_FROM)over(order by DATE_FROM)) is null 
then '2099-01-01' else dateadd(d,-1,lead(DATE_FROM)over(order by DATE_FROM)) 
 end as DATE_TO 
 from cte a
```

Output:

```
EMP LOCATION            DATE_FROM   DATE_TO
Pinal   Bangalore       2020-01-01  2020-01-03
Pinal   Uttar Pradesh   2020-01-04  2020-01-19
Pinal   Mumbai          2020-01-20  2020-01-21
Pinal   Bangalore       2020-01-22  2099-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive cte to group the consecutive rows together and then use the lead function to get the next date.

**Adding row_number to the data:**

```
select a.*,
       row_number() over (Partition by Emp Order by date_worked) as rownum
INTO #Emp1
From #Emp a
```

**Recursive cte to group:**

```
IF object_ID ('tempdb.dbo.#Temp1') is not null DROP TABLE #Temp1

DECLARE @int int=0

;WITH CTE as
(
SELECT *,1 as grp 
FROM #Emp1
WHERE rownum=1 

UNION ALL

SELECT t.*,
        CASE WHEN c.City=t.City then grp 
        else grp+1 end as grp
FROM #Emp1 t 
INNER JOIN CTE c
            ON t.rownum=c.rownum+1 and t.Emp=c.Emp
)

SELECT * 
INTO #temp1 
FROM CTE
OPTION (maxrecursion 0);
```

**Lead function to get the end date:**

```
SELECT emp,
       min(date_worked) as date_from,
       ISNULL(DATEADD(d,-1,lead(min(date_worked)) Over (Partition by emp Order by min(date_worked))),'01Jan2099') as date_to,
       City
from #temp1
Group by grp,emp,City
```

Hope this gives you the desired result.